# Parse the "interpreted" HTML code from a URL with urllib and Python

Tags: python, html, urllib

Is there a way to read the "interpreted" HTML code from a URL?

Let's say there is a website that allows you to make a search and then display 10 elements. For example, you search "shoes" and then you have 10 different shoes that show up with a link for each.

If I display the source code, I only see this:

```
<shoes-search inputs-var="ShoesSearch">xxx...</shoes-search>
<style>
</style>
```

But I can't see the different div and links for the 10 shoes.

But if I right-click on the shoes and inspect element (on chrome) I can see all the 10 shoes div and links.

I think the difference is that when I display the source code, it is not interpreted, but when I click on inspect element, the same source code is interpreted.

My problem is that I am using this code:

```
import urllib.request

url="https://www.website.com/search/"
sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htmlSource = str(sock.read())
sock.close()
```

And I get the HTML contents without the 10 links for each shoe.

Is there any way to get the interpreted HTML content instead, i.e., as when I "inspect element" using my browser?

Comment: It looks like you might have JS framework at play here too...react? Angular?

Comment: by "interpreted", I think you mean the result of running some on-page javascript. That's definitely not possible using a regular HTML parser. There may be tools for doing it, but I'm not sure. What might well be happening is that the site is getting this data from an API, which you might be able to access. But that depends on the site, you'll probably have to google to see if there's an API and if so how to use it.

Comment: You can try scraping the page using [Selenium instead](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think Selenium can be the solution

Comment: I had the same problem as you, and Selenium is indeed the solution for Dynamic HTML. It's kinda similar to BeautifulSoup in its use, so you shouldn't have problems